# Is there anyway to generalize eventHandlers for winForm components

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have to create 6 textBoxes which accepts only numbers. I have used keyPress event for this purpose. But I have to repeat the same eventHandler code for 6 times, which just varies in the name of the formComponent. Can anyone explain how to reduce the size of the code? pls. code is

```
   private void textBox1_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) || e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox1.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox1.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Console.Beep(1000, 500);
            MessageBox.Show("Only numbers allowed!","Error");
        }
     }

    private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) || e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox1.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
        {
            return;
        }
        else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox1.Text.Contains('.'))
        {
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            e.Handled = true;
            Console.Beep(1000, 500);
            MessageBox.Show("Only numbers allowed!", "Error");
        }
    }     AND THIS REPEATS FOR 4 MORE TIMES
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subscribe to the same method and cast `sender` object to a specific control, here is an example for your code:

```
private void textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
{
    var textBox=(TextBox)sender; //text box which raised the event

    if (char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) || (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back) || e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox.Text.Contains('.'))
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == (char)Keys.Back)
    {
        return;
    }
    else if (e.KeyChar == '.' && !textBox.Text.Contains('.'))
    {
        return;
    }
    else
    {
        e.Handled = true;
        Console.Beep(1000, 500);
        MessageBox.Show("Only numbers allowed!","Error");
    }
 }
```

Subscribing to Events:

```
textBox1.KeyPress+=textBox_KeyPress;
textBox2.KeyPress+=textBox_KeyPress;
...
```

or you can select same methods for `KeyPress` event from Property Grid in IDE

Comment: Very much thanx.....but a small edit if we keep += the number of times the error pops up is increasing +1 for every time an alphabet is pressed. Your code gave me another simple idea.. We can just use the textBox_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressArgs e) as a function.I

Answer (score 0):

I have called the event function in this manner.

```
    private void textBox2_KeyPress(object sender, KeyPressEventArgs e)
    {
       textBox_KeyPress(sender,e);
    }
```